# Decrease execution time of SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I've got a question in terms of processing and making a query more efficient whilst maintaining its accuracy. Before I display the query I'd like to point out some basics of it.

I've got a case that manipulates the `where`-clause to get all childs of the parent. Basically I've got two types of data that I need to display; a red and a green type. The red type has a column (`TRK_TrackerGroup_LKID2`) set to `NULL` by default, whereas the green data has a value in said column (ranging from **5-7**).

My problem is that I need to extract both types of data to accurately get a count of outstanding issues in a view, but doing so (by adding the case) the execution time goes from **< 1 second** to well over **15 seconds**.

This is the query (with the mentioned case):

```
SELECT TS.id        AS TrackerStartDateID,
       TSM.mappingtypeid,
       TSM.maptoid,
       TFLK.trk_trackergroup_lkid,
       Count(TF.id) AS Cnt
FROM   [dbo].[trk_startdate] TS
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[trk_startdatemap] TSM
               ON TS.id = TSM.trk_startdateid
                  AND TSM.deletedflag = 0
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[trk_trackerfeatures] TF
               ON TF.trk_startdateid = TS.id
                  AND TF.deletedflag = 0
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[trk_trackerfeatures_lk] TFLK
               ON TFLK.id = TF.trk_feature_lkid
WHERE  TS.deletedflag = 0
       AND TF.applicabletoproject = 1
       AND TF.readyforwork = CASE  -- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                               WHEN TF.trk_trackerstatus_lkid2 IS NULL THEN 0
                               ELSE 1
                             END
       AND TF.datestamp = (SELECT Max(TF2.datestamp)
                           FROM   [dbo].[trk_trackerfeatures] TF2
                                  INNER JOIN [dbo].[trk_trackerfeatures_lk] TFLK2
                                          ON TFLK2.id = TF2.trk_feature_lkid
                           WHERE  TF.trk_startdateid = TF2.trk_startdateid
                                  AND TFLK2.trk_trackergroup_lkid = TFLK.trk_trackergroup_lkid)
GROUP  BY TS.id,
          TSM.mappingtypeid,
          TSM.maptoid,
          TFLK.trk_trackergroup_lkid,
          TF.datestamp
```

It functions as a 'parent' in the sense that it grabs the latest inserted data-set (using DateStamp) from every single child-group. This is necessary to produce a parent-report in SSRS report at a later time, but at the moment my problem (as mentioned above) is the execution time.

I'd like to hear if there are any suggestions on how to decrease the execution time whilst maintaining the accuracy of the query.

Expected output:

[image]

Without the case I get this:

[image]

Comment: `AND TF.readyforwork = CASE` is this the problem case?

Comment: Indeed. I attempted to bold the case to properly show what the issue was, but seems like a code-markup overrides any font-styles.

Comment: Can you provide [sample input and expect output](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: use `--` to indicate comment

Comment: @destination-data no input required. Will edit with expected output

Comment: If you dont show input, how we will know how create the output?

Comment: It's easier to work on a query when you've been supplied input and output.  It gives you something to validate your results against.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Not really sure how to supply that except the execution times (without case < 1 second exec, with case => 15 seconds)

Comment: You use something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e690c/2 or http://rextester.com to create a sample db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this condition cant use `INDEX`

```
AND TF.readyforwork = CASE  -- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                        WHEN TF.trk_trackerstatus_lkid2 IS NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                      END
```

Try to change it to

```
AND ( TF.readyforwork = 0 and TF.trk_trackerstatus_lkid2 IS NULL 
   OR TF.readyforwork = 1 and TF.trk_trackerstatus_lkid2 IS NOT NULL
    )
```

But again you should check with `EXPLAIN ANALIZE` to test if your query is using index or not.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. My bad. Sorry for the cancer-post. Seems to have been a blunder on my side not seeing that I could use AND in a case... :/

Answer (score 0):

The most problematic bit of your query seems to be the correlated subquery, because you must call it for every possible row.

You should optimize this first. To do so you can add indexes that the engine could use to quickly calculate that value on each row.

Based on your query I would add these two indexes multiples :

1. On Table `trackerfeatures`, index fields : `trk_startdateid, datestamp`
2. On Table `trk_trackerfeatures_lk`, index fields : `id, trk_trackergroup_lkid`

Comment: Having the subquery in the default query (without the case) executes in less than a second. Whereas if I add the case I get an execution of more than 15 seconds. 

This leads me to believe it's more likely a problem with the case than the subquery